# How to rewrite this powershell cmdlet to produce specific output?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am not good with PS but I need help with this..

```
Get-WmiObject -class DCIM_BIOSEnumeration -Namespace root\dcim\sysman | Where-Object {$_.AttributeName -Match "Trusted Platform Module Activation"} | Select CurrentValue
```

When it runs, it will return either a 1 or 2 as the CurrentValue.

I need the script to output "Detected" if the result is 2 and nothing (null) if it is 1.

Anyone able to help out? Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `if` statement to determine whether to output "Detected" or not:

```
$CurrentValue = Get-WmiObject -class DCIM_BIOSEnumeration -Namespace root\dcim\sysman | Where-Object {
  $_.AttributeName -Match "Trusted Platform Module Activation"
} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CurrentValue

if($CurrentValue -eq 2) {
    "Detected"
}
```